# transform list of object into object

Tags: javascript

I have input list of object,

```
[
{"id":1,"name":"USD - US Dollar","country":"US","created_at":"2018-05-28 
14:54:24","updated_at":"2018-05-28 14:54:24"},
{"id":2,"name":"TH- Thai Bat","country":"TH","created_at":"2018-05-28 
14:54:24","updated_at":"2018-05-28 14:54:24"}
]
```

I want to transform into , anyone please guide me.

```
{"US": "USD - US Dollar","TH": "TH- Thai Bat"}
```

Comment: I can't wrap my head around how this is an issue for someone with your level. Simply do `var obj = {};
for(var i = 0; i < l.length; i++)
 obj[l[i].country] = l[i].name;`

Comment: @ZohirSalakCeNa you are genius , thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `reduce` to turn an array into a single object:

```js
const input = [
{"id":1,"name":"USD - US Dollar","country":"US","created_at":"2018-05-28 14:54:24","updated_at":"2018-05-28 14:54:24"},
{"id":2,"name":"TH- Thai Bat","country":"TH","created_at":"2018-05-28 14:54:24","updated_at":"2018-05-28 14:54:24"}
];

const output = input.reduce((a, { name, country }) => {
  a[country] = name;
  return a;
}, {});
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to `reduce` you can also:

```js
arr = [
    {"id":1,"name":"USD - US Dollar","country":"US","created_at":"2018-05-28 14:54:24","updated_at":"2018-05-28 14:54:24"},
    {"id":2,"name":"TH- Thai Bat","country":"TH","created_at":"2018-05-28 14:54:24","updated_at":"2018-05-28 14:54:24"}
]

obj = {}

arr.forEach(function(el) {
    obj[el.country] = el.name
})

console.log(obj)
```